# How can i customize the MKMapview Annotation With Next and Previous Functionality?

Tags: objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

[image]

HI I have requirement to Implement Next and Previous functionality in the MKMapAnnotationView as shown in the Image.I have got reference from [Here](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) for making custom annotation but how can i change the next or previous annotation by clicking Next and Previous button.Please provide some Hint or idea regarding this.I am stack at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` and `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.

Here an example how to use the `rightCalloutAccessoryView`.

```
    -(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:  (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

 if ([annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;
}

static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

[pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];
if([annotation isKindOfClass:[ASPinAnnotation class]])
{
    [pinView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
}
else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[ASAddAutomatPin class]])
{
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:[annotation title] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [pinView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];
    [pinView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
}
```

And to get notified when a calloutAccessoryView is tapped you have to use this function in your delegate:

```
   -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
   {

if([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure)
{
    ASAddViewController *addController = [[ASAddViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
    [addController setDelegate:self];
    [self.controller presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

}
```